# Unable to import db object more than once in flask and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a couple of modules: start.py, user.py, projects.py

In start.py I have:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'my_database_URI'
db = SQAlchemy(app)
db.createAll()
```

I need to use the db object from both user.py and projects.py. If I import it like so:

```
from start import db
```

then I get an error if I do this in both modules. If I only import it to user.py, for example - then it works fine. The error I'm getting is "ImportError: cannot import name db".

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Sounds like a circular import. Can you post the import statments from each file?

Comment: It's there in the post - both user.py and projects.py have "from start import db" at the top of the file. But I think I get what you say... start.py also imports both user.py and projects.py. Could this be this circular import?

Comment: This is a circular import problem which at it's core is design problem. You'll need to make some changes, why are you importing those files back into `start.py`?

Comment: It's my first python app ever, so I wasn't even thinking about this. The reason I'm importing those into start.py is because they contain relevant route methods (for example, user registration sits in user.py). So I have only imported the namespace under which the user.py and projects.py sit, and now it works. If there's a better way to do it, I'll be happy to learn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this is a circular import problem.

The way that I've gotten around this is by having another file, a `shared.py` file in the root directory. In that file, create the database object,

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

In your `start.py`, don't create a new db object. Instead, do

```
from shared import db
db.init_app(app)
```

In any place that you want to use the db object, including your models file, import it from `shared.py`:

```
from shared import db
# do stuff with db
```

This way, the object in the shared file will have been initialized with the app context, and there's no chance of circular imports.

Comment: You saved me! Thanks.